# How do I use firebase auth and other features on IOS, with react native

Tags: ios, react-native, authentication, firebase-authentication

I know that there is an option to create an IOS app in your firebase project, however I do not still understand it. I am using a tutorial, but the tutorial uses a web app, and put the following code into the app.json file:

```
"config" : {
          "firebase": {
          "apiKey": "**********************************",
          "authDomain": "**********************************",
          "databaseURL": "**********************************",
          "projectId": "**********************************",
          "storageBucket": "**********************************",
          "messagingSenderId": "**********************************",
          "appId": "**********************************",
          "measurementId": "**********************************"
        }
      }
```

I am sure this wouldn't work on IOS, since this is fore web apps, but can someone please simplify adding an IOS app to firebase, using react native. Again, react native, because I am nor using Xcode to do this.

I have tried to understand the process, but I am still struggling to grasp everything

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you have to download:

1. Register your app in your Firebase project in the Firebase console.
2. Download the `Google-Service.plist` file that this give you.
3. Add that file to your app in Xcode.

For a more complete step-by-step walkthrough, see the [Add Firebase to your Apple project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much. But, what do I need to do in react native, since that is what  I am using?

Comment: Your React Native project comes with an Xcode project for iOS, and you'll need to add the `plist` file to that. If you're using the `react-native-firebase` package, the process for that is quite well documented here: https://rnfirebase.io/#3-ios-setup